# .htaccess, не пашет RewriteRule - где ошибка?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, сервер, веб-сервер

Хочу, чтобы все ссылки, начинающиеся на **/f** переводились на **/files**

Пишу `RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ /files/$1 [R=301,L]`

Задаю **/f/my.zip** – не пашет, хотя файл **/files/my.zip** есть.
*Где ошибка?*

p.s. Пробовал и `Redirect 301 /f /files` и `RedirectMatch 301 ^/f /files` - бесполезно...

Answer (score 1):

Ёлки-палки, оказывается просто была отключена обработка статических файлов **Apache**.

Хостер ответил и включил... :))